# Why does the "AddOre" Function doesn't work?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been reading the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" and trying to learn Python on my own, I decided to practice what I've learned in chapter one and got a little bit confused by this code and why it doesn't work.
Been sitting and trying to figure it out but still didn't make it.

I've tried to switch the given values of the function and other stuff as well but if I am being honest I don't really know what I am doing I will be very glad if someone explains causes the problem and how to fix it, here's the code :

```
Mine = {'Bronze': 10,'Iron': 40,'Gold': 2,'Diamonds':2}

def ShowMine(cave):

    for k, v in cave.items():
        Total_Res = 0
        print("There is : " + str(k))
        print("And there is : " + str(v) + " of it")
        Total_Res += int(v)
    print("total ores in the cave : " + str(Total_Res))
def AddOre(cave, ore):

    for k,v in cave.items():
       cave += ore.values()

Mine1 = {'Bronzze': 10,'Iron': 0,'Gold': 2,'Diamonds':4}

ShowMine(Mine)

AddOre(Mine,Mine1)

ShowMine(Mine)
```

I expect the code to output the added values from Mine1 to the original Mine created at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The two arguments `cave` and `ore` of the function `AddOre` are both dictionaries. The function then iterates over the items of the first arguments and in each iteration tries to add the return value of `ore.values()`, which is a list, to the dictionary `cave`. This doesn't work and I'm not sure what the result of that operation is even supposed to be.

What you want to do, I'm guessing, is to add the values of the second argument to the values of the first argument identifying them by their keys. This can be done by this code:

```py
def AddOre(cave, ore):
    for k, _ in cave.items():
        if k in ore:
            cave[k] += ore[k]
    for k, v in ore.items():
        if k not in cave:
            cave[k] = v
```

The first loop adds the values of the ores that already exist in the cave and the second loop adds all the new ores. There might be a simpler way to do the same thing with native addition operations of list and dictionary types, but I can't think of any right now.